# Warshall's Algorithm for Transitive Closure(Python)

Tags: python, algorithm

I am writing a program that uses Warshall's algorithm for to find a transitive closure of a matrix that represents a relation. Here is a link to the algorithm in psuedocode: http://people.cs.pitt.edu/~adamlee/courses/cs0441/lectures/lecture27-closures.pdf (page 21).

```
def warshall(a):

    assert (len(row) == len(a) for row in a)
    n = len(a)
    for k in range (1,n):
        for i in range (1,n):
            for j in range (1,n):
                a[i][j] = a[i][j] or (a[i][k] and a[k][j])


   return M

   print warshall([[0,0,0,1],[1,0,1,0],[1,0,0,1],[0,0,1,0]])
```

I should be getting [[1,0,1,1],[1,0,1,1],[1,0,1,1],[1,0,1,1]]

Am getting [[0,0,0,1],[1,0,1,1],[1,0,1,1],[0,0,1,1]]

Comment: Change range(1,n) to range(n)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

in the lecture, indexes are from 1 to n, but here, you have to go from 0 to n-1, so the `range` function must be `range(0,n)` or, more concisely `range(n)` (also, it's `return a`, not M)

```
def warshall(a):
    assert (len(row) == len(a) for row in a)
    n = len(a)
    for k in range(n):
        for i in range(n):
            for j in range(n):
                a[i][j] = a[i][j] or (a[i][k] and a[k][j])
    return a
```