# compute transitive closure of directed graph with networkx

Tags: python, networkx, directed-graph

My efforts to find how to compute transitive closure of directed graph with networkx have come up surprisingly empty.  It seems unlikely that this is not in networkx, so ... where is it?  (I am aware that Sage includes this functionality.)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22519680/warshalls-algorithm-for-transitive-closurepython?

Comment: Thanks, but I'm familiar with the Floyd-Warshall algorithm.  Additionally, as noted in the question, Sage implements it.  I want to know where it's hidden (?) in networkx.  (With a possible answer of "nowhere".)

Answer (score 1):

There is no transitive closure function in NetworkX.  But I think you can do it in one line :-).
(untested)

```
In [1]: import networkx as nx

In [2]: G = nx.DiGraph([(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 2), (3, 4)])

In [3]: H = nx.DiGraph([(u,v,{'d':l}) for u,adj in nx.floyd_warshall(G).items() for v,l in adj.items() if l > 0 and l < float('inf')])

In [4]: H.adj
Out[4]: 
{1: {2: {'d': 1.0}, 3: {'d': 2.0}, 4: {'d': 3.0}},
 2: {3: {'d': 1.0}, 4: {'d': 2.0}},
 3: {2: {'d': 1.0}, 4: {'d': 1.0}},
 4: {}}
```